# Twilio not sending webhooks in Progammable Chat

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I would like to ask a question or maybe report a bug after solving my doubts. I started working with Programmable Chat and Twilio do not want to send a webhook to specific url but only when I'm sending message from my PHP code. I downloaded example node app and sending message from that, everything is working really nice, I'm getting post request from Twilio but if only I will send message from PHP, nothing at all. And strange is, after sending message from PHP, it will appear immediately in chat which means that it's working.

How does it possible? Could it mean that Twilio on theirs backend has an a bug when they receive message from PHP and becuase of that they are not fire webhook event?

I eliminated all differences, everything is that same beside that one message is sending from PHP and another from node. Same situation from API Explorer.

[Gif presentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWu6c.gif)

Answer (score 5):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you send messages to Programmable Chat from the REST API then webhooks aren't triggered. I think the reasoning is because you are making the call from your server, then your server is already aware that you are sending a message and you don't need to receive a webhook to do so. It also saves from the potential of infinite loops (if your webhook sends a message via the REST API, the requests would just go in circles).

So, it's not a bug, but a design choice. If you need to trigger your webhooks when you send a message from the REST API, you will need to make the webhook from your own server.

Comment: Very well explained. Thank you.